# Can the new Mac OS Shortcuts be triggered from a folder similar to the legacy folder actions?

Tags: automator, shortcuts-app

I would like to be able to set up an export from Lightroom Classic to a folder on disk that automatically imports the pictures to an Apple Photos album. Mac OS has a legacy feature called "folder actions" that can call an Apple Script or an Automator Workflow when files are dropped in the folder, can this functionality be duplicated with the new Mac OS Siri Shortcuts?

If this isn't the right approach is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcuts App for Mac doesn't support Folder Actions.

As a workaround, you can use Automator to set up the Folder Actions to trigger Shortcuts. (If you want time based trigger, use Calendar to schedule the trigger.)

Add a "Run Shell Script" action for "shortcuts run "shortcut name"".

[image: Automator to Run Shell Script]

Comment: how would you pass in files to the shortcuts app?

Comment: @treeseal7, you can use Pass input: as arguments to get the file name for processing.